# Из JSON в map используя GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Имеется JSON строка:

```
{"str1": "str1",
"str2": "str2",
"str3": {
    "str4": 1.3762,
    "str5": 1.9558,
    "srt6": 3.2623,}}
```

Нужно записать содержимое str3 в HashMap.

Пробовал так, но компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Double>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, Double> myMap = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, type);
```

Ошибка:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

[gt22](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/222961/gt22) прав -- у вас `JsonReader` под капотом встретил строку, а не ожидаемую `{`. Кроме того, у `srt6` есть ещё и висячая запятая, которая препятствует парсингу JSON-документа. И, к тому же, у вас ожидаемый тип, похоже, нацелен на весь JSON-документ, который не соответствует такому типу (на самом высоком уровне нет ниодного числового значения).

Но, тем не менее, есть два принципиально разных подхода к решению таких вопросов: или использовать объектную модель JSON, или читать данные потоково. У каждого есть свои особенности, преимущества и недостатки.

В первом случае (в случае с объектной моделью) если допускается, что размером данных можно принебречь ввиду их небольшого размера и парсинг обойдётся дёшево, можно просто прочитать JSON документ как `JsonObject` и уже с его помощью добраться до `str3` и десериализировать его значение как `Map<String, Double>`:

```java
    final JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, JsonObject.class);
    final JsonElement str3JsonElement = jsonObject.get("str3");
    final Map<String, Double> values = gson.fromJson(str3JsonElement, stringToDoubleMapType);
    System.out.println(values);
```

Если же размер входных данных большой и тратить память на парсинг бесполезных данных нельзя, нужно прочитать входной документ как поток токенов, разбирая токены вручную. И уже, исходя из того или иного состояния, извлечь значение `str3`. Поэтому реализация такого парсера уже посложней:

```java
final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(bufferedReader);
final Map<String, Double> values = extractValues(gson, jsonReader, "str3");
System.out.println(values);
```

```java
private static Map<String, Double> extractValues(final Gson gson, final JsonReader jsonReader, final String expectedName)
        throws IOException {
    Map<String, Double> values = null;
    // убеждаемся, что первым токеном является {
    jsonReader.beginObject();
    // и читаем все токены, пока не встретится }
    while ( jsonReader.peek() != END_OBJECT ) {
        // извлекаем имя свойства
        final String actualName = jsonReader.nextName();
        if ( actualName.equals(expectedName) ) {
            // и если оно совпадает с expectedName (str3) -- проделегировать десериализацию Gson-у
            values = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, stringToDoubleMapType);
        } else {
            // иначе проигнорировать значение
            jsonReader.skipValue();
        }
    }
    // убеждаемся, что объект был прочитан полностью
    jsonReader.endObject();
    return values;
}
```

В обоих случаях на stdout будет выведено:

> {str4=1.3762, str5=1.9558, srt6=3.2623}

Answer (score 0):

Похже JSON который вы обробатываете не совсем соответствует тому что в посте, ибо GSON ругается на то что первым симболом видет строку а не начало объекта (`{`).

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/144462)

Comment: @Vadizar В данном случае проблема именно в отсутствии `{`, её добавление должно решить проблему.